# How to set pandas dataframe to NaN using last_valid_index() of another column

Tags: python, pandas

How to set the column of a pandas dataframe to NaN using the index above the `last_valid_index()` of another column to NaN.

In [2]: df

```
          A         B
0  1.068932 -0.794307
2 -0.470056  1.192211
4 -0.284561  0.756029
6  1.037563 -0.267820
8 -0.538478 NaN
9. 1.03733  NaN
10.1.037562 NaN
```

For example: `df.B.last_valid_index()` will give `6`. So I want all rows in column A where `index < 6` be set to `NaN`

final result should be:

```
     A         B
0   NaN    -0.794307
2   NaN     1.192211
4   NaN     0.756029
6   NaN    -0.267820
8 -0.538478 NaN
9. 1.03733  NaN
10.1.037562 NaN
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`last_valid_index` returns a row label. Therefore use [`df.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#different-choices-for-indexing) to select columns and rows by label, and assign a new value:

```
idx = df['B'].last_valid_index()
df.loc[:idx, 'A'] = np.nan
```

---

For example,

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
nan = np.nan
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, 9, 2, 9, 1, 7, 0], 'B': [4.0, 0.0, 7.0, 7.0, nan, nan, nan]},
                  index=range(0,13,2))

idx = df['B'].last_valid_index()
df.loc[:idx, 'A'] = np.nan
print(df)
```

yields

```
      A    B
0   NaN  4.0
2   NaN  0.0
4   NaN  7.0
6   NaN  7.0
8   1.0  NaN
10  7.0  NaN
12  0.0  NaN
```